# predict() raises ValueError('train and valid dataset categorical_feature do not match.')

Tags: python, predict, lightgbm

I have used bayesian HPO to optimize a LightGBM model for an regression objective. To do so I adjusted a [classification template](https://www.kaggle.com/rohitgr/lgbm-bayesianoptimization-eda) to work with my data. The in-sample fit works so far but when I try to do a out-of-sample fit using `predict()` I get an error message.

The function for my out-of-sample fit looks like this :

```
def test_kfold(params, train, train_y, test, cv):
test_preds = 0.
valid_preds = np.zeros(train_y.shape)

for fold, (train_ix, valid_ix) in enumerate(cv.split(train, train_y)):
    print(f"\nFOLD: {fold+1} {'='*50}")
    X_train, X_valid = train.iloc[train_ix], train.iloc[valid_ix]
    y_train, y_valid = train_y.iloc[train_ix], train_y.iloc[valid_ix]
    
    lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train, free_raw_data=False)
    lgb_valid = lgb.Dataset(X_valid, y_valid, free_raw_data=False)
    
    rlf = lgb.train(params, lgb_train, 5000, valid_sets=[lgb_train, lgb_valid], verbose_eval=250, early_stopping_rounds=50)
    valid_preds[valid_ix] = rlf.predict(train.iloc[valid_ix], num_iterations=rlf.best_iteration)
    test_preds += rlf.predict(test, num_iterations=rlf.best_iteration)

print(f'Valid CV: {sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(train_y, valid_preds, squared = False)}')
test_preds /= cv.n_splits

return test_preds
```

The parameters and the actual function call looks like this :

```
params = {
    'feature_fraction': LGB_BO.max['params']['feature_fraction'],
    'lambda_l1': LGB_BO.max['params']['lambda_l1'],
    'lambda_l2': LGB_BO.max['params']['lambda_l2'],
    'learning_rate': LGB_BO.max['params']['learning_rate'],
    'max_depth': int(np.round(LGB_BO.max['params']['max_depth'])),
    'min_data_in_leaf': int(np.round(LGB_BO.max['params']['min_data_in_leaf'])),
    'min_gain_to_split': LGB_BO.max['params']['min_gain_to_split'],
    'min_sum_hessian_in_leaf': LGB_BO.max['params']['min_sum_hessian_in_leaf'],
    'num_leaves': int(np.round(LGB_BO.max['params']['num_leaves'])),
    'max_bin': 255,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.8,
    'bagging_freq': 3,
    'save_binary': True,
    'seed': 7,
    'feature_fraction_seed': 7,
    'bagging_seed': 7,
    'drop_seed': 7,
    'data_random_seed': 7,
    'objective': 'regression',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'verbose': 1,
    'metric': 'rmse',
    'is_unbalance': True,
    'boost_from_average': True,
    'n_jobs': -1
}

# 5-Fold testing
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')    
    test_preds = test_kfold(params, train, train_y, test, KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=7, shuffle=True))
```

Calling the function raises the following error :

```
In [181]: test_preds += rlf.predict(test.drop(['avg_power'], axis = 1), num_iterations=rlf.best_iteration)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
          File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16312/2582764377.py", line 1, in <module>
            test_preds += rlf.predict(test.drop(['avg_power'], axis = 1), num_iterations=rlf.best_iteration)
        
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16312/2582764377.py", line 1, in <module>
        test_preds += rlf.predict(test.drop(['avg_power'], axis = 1), num_iterations=rlf.best_iteration)
    
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 3538, in predict
        return predictor.predict(data, start_iteration, num_iteration,
    
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 820, in predict
        data = _data_from_pandas(data, None, None, self.pandas_categorical)[0]
    
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 575, in _data_from_pandas
        raise ValueError('train and valid dataset categorical_feature do not match.')
    
    ValueError: train and valid dataset categorical_feature do not match.
```

The train dataset is splitted in an single array train_y which contains the variable of interest and a datafame train which contains all other variables used for the regression.
The test dataset contains all features of train and train_y in one dataset.

I hope that this information are enough to clarify the problem. Sadly, I can't share the acutal dataset.

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer to your question if you put in the effort to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add all necessary import statements, include versions of packages you have installed (like the output of `conda env export`), try using a publicly-available dataset like those in [`sklearn.datasets`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/toy_dataset.html), and try removing parameters from `params` to simplify the case as much as possible.

Comment: @mugdi are you able to resolve this ?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar Sadly I gave up on this and moved back to R to solve my use-case. Sry for that!

Comment: @mugdi I have solved it as i was using replace with np.nan as a null value filter which still keeps some null values(NaN's) which resulted in new set of categories while predicting

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was solved by removing categories unseen during the train from the test.

Here is an example of a transformer that would solve this issue. Because all unknown categories in the train set would be replaced with `Other` during `transform` LightGBM won't encounter unseen categorical values.

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


class TakeTopK(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
"""
 Select top K categorical features in each column, and replace all other values with `Other`.
"""
    def __init__(self, k=20, cat_feat, cont_feat):
        self.largest_cat = {}
        self.k = k
        self.cat_feat = cat_feat
        self.cont_feat = cont_feat

        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        for col in self.cat_feat:
            self.largest_cat[col] = X[col].value_counts().nlargest(self.k).index
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        Xt = pd.DataFrame()
        for col in self.cat_feat:
        # LightGBM would pick up the `'category'` type, so it does not need to be provided explicitly to the classifier.
            Xt[col] = pd.Series(np.where(X[col].isin(self.largest_cat[col]), X[col], 'Other'), dtype='category')
        Xt[self.cont_feat] = X[self.cont_feat].astype(float)
        return Xt
    


pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('top_k', TakeTopK(50)),
    ('clf', lgb.LGBMModel())    
])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).